# Differences between declare, typeset and local variable in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, variables, scope, declare

When typing variables in Bash, what is the difference between `declare` and `typeset`? When used inside a function: what is the difference between `declare` and `typeset` and `local`?

The only difference I have come across is that typeset is portable to ksh scripts. Other than that, are there any reasons why one should be preferred over the other?

UPDATE: Added `local` to the question.

Comment: similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30362831/471376).

Comment: is a variable declared with `typeset` or `declare`  *local*? if not how do we make them local?

Comment: https://opensource.apple.com/source/zsh/zsh-65/zsh/Doc/help/typeset.auto.html

Answer (score 41):

- Difference between `typeset` and `declare`:

The former is more portable(e.g. ksh), while the latter is more preferable when portability is not a concern.

- Difference between `declare`(or `typeset`) and `local` when used inside a function:

The former implies the latter, but more powerful. For example, `declare -i x` makes `x` have the `integer` attribute, `declare -r x` makes `x` readonly, etc.

Comment: `local` and `declare` are mostly identical and take all the same arguments with two exceptions: local will fail if not used within a function, and local with no args filters output to print only locals, declare doesn't.

Comment: @ormaaj you're right, I didn't realize that `local` supports options too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: so a variable declared with `typeset` or `declare` is *local*? seems like that question is the most obvious question to answer.

Comment: @AlexanderMills 

Using `declare` or `typeset` without the `-g` modifier inside a function will declare a local variable. `local` will of course also create a local variable. Any other method of declaring a variable inside a function will create a global variable.

Comment: I know that this is old, but it's useful to note that within a function, `declare` and `local` are identical (apart from using `local` without parameters). If you use `local -g`, the variable will counterintuitively be global! For me, the only useful distinction is visual, so that the human reader knows that `local` is intended to be local, whereas `declare` is intended to be used with `-g`.

Comment: So… Is there ever a reason to use `readonly`, really?

Comment: @lindhe code robustness?

Comment: @RonJohn instead of using `declare`, I mean.

Comment: @lindhe testing shows that `readonly` in a function makes the variable global in scope.

Comment: Thus, I see no use for `readonly`. Do you?

Answer (score 15):

As far as bash is concerned, no, there is no difference. In fact, the manpage has them share the same definition

> declare [-aAfFilrtux] [-p]
>   [name[=value] ...]
>  typeset
>   [-aAfFilrtux] [-p] [name[=value]
>   ...]
>     Declare  variables and/or
>   give them attributes.  If no names are
>   given then display the values of
>   variables.  The -p option will display
>   the attributes and values of each
>   name...

I also found [this little tidbit](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/declareref.html) which further substantiates my claim as well as the `ksh` portability you mentioned.

> The declare or typeset builtins,
>   ***which are exact synonyms***, permit modifying the properties of variables.
>   This is a very weak form of the typing
>   [1] available in certain programming
>   languages. The declare command is
>   specific to version 2 or later of
>   Bash. The typeset command also works
>   in ksh scripts.

Comment: "help typeset" tells me that it's obsolete. Deprecated in favor of "declare".

Comment: this is a good example of the problems in the bash documentation and theres inconsistency with command line help (using the 'help' command) and the manual pages, (using 'man bash' and going to SHELL BUILTINS) and the builtin page (using 'man builtins'). There are also some typos in there, so be careful

Comment: "When used in a function, declare makes each name local, as with the local command, unless the -g option is used." from https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html

Answer (score 7):

In the Bash manual under section [4.2 Bash Builtin Commands](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC60) it states:

> 'typeset'
>             typeset [-afFrxi] [-p] [NAME[=VALUE] ...]
>        The 'typeset' command is supplied for compatibility with the Korn
>        shell; however, it has been deprecated in favor of the 'declare'
>        builtin command.