# what is difference in `declare -r` and `readonly` in bash?

Tags: bash

In bash, what is the difference in `declare -r` and `readonly`?

```
$ declare -r a="a1"
$ readonly b="b1"
```

I'm not sure which to choose.

Answer (score 56):

**tl;dr** `readonly` uses the default scope of *global* even inside functions.  `declare` uses scope *local* when in a function (unless `declare -g`).

At first glance, no difference.

Examining using [declare -p](http://ss64.com/bash/declare.html)

```sh
$ declare -r a=a1
$ readonly b=b1
$ declare -p a b
declare -r a="a1"
declare -r b="b1"

# variable a and variable b are the same
```

Now review the difference when defined within a function

```sh
# define variables inside function A
$ function A() {
      declare -r x=x1
      readonly y=y1
      declare -p x y
  }

$ A
declare -r x="x1"
declare -r y="y1"

# ***calling function A again will incur an error because variable y
#    was defined using readonly so y is in the global scope***

$ A
-bash: y: readonly variable
declare -r x="x1"
declare -r y="y1"

# after call of function A, the variable y is still defined

$ declare -p x y
bash: declare: x: not found
declare -r y="y1"
```

To add more nuance, `readonly` may be used to change a locally declared variable property to *readonly*, not affecting scope.

```sh
$ function A() {
    declare a="a1"
    declare -p a
    readonly a
    declare -p a
}

$ A
declare -- a="a1"
declare -r a="a1"

$ declare -p a
-bash: declare: a: not found
```

---

Note: adding `-g` flag to the `declare` statement (e.g. `declare -rg a="a1"`) makes the variable scope *global*.  (thanks @chepner).

Note: `readonly` is a "*Special Builtin*".  If Bash is in `POSIX` mode then `readonly` (and not `declare`) has the effect ["*returning an error status will not cause the shell to exit*"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode).

Comment: Note that as of `bash` 4.2, `declare -gr` seems to be identical to `readonly`.

Comment: Looks like there is no difference between `readonly` and `declare -r`.  `declare` inside a function would always create local variables unless the `-g` flag is specified.

Comment: i like when you answer your self, and answer after 4+ years is still best answer

Comment: Re: "`readonly` will make the variable scope *global*": That's misleading; if a variable is already local, then `readonly` won't suddenly make it global. It would be more correct to say that `readonly` doesn't affect variable scope at all, and global scope is the default scope.

Comment: Thanks @ruakh .  How embarrassing, that was very poorly worded for a long time.  Fixed.

Comment: How does `local -r` tie into this?

Comment: "_How does `local -r` tie into this?_" `local -r` would create a variable that is local-scope and readonly.  Try it yourself `function foo() { local -r bar=1; echo bar is $bar; declare -p bar; bar=2; }; foo`.