# Bash Variable Scope Leak

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

Usually, I see questions about people not being able to access variables from outside their scope. However, I seem to be experiencing the opposite: I am seeing variables still having values from inner scopes they should have given up afterwards. For example (making svn aliases similar to [git aliases](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases)):

```
function svn() {
    case $@ in
        alias*) shift 1;
            for i in "$@"; do
                if [[ "$i" == "-t" ]];
                then
                    j="$i,$j"
                elif [[ "$i" == "-f" ]];
                    k="$i,$j"
                fi
            done

            echo "i = $i"
            echo "j = $j"
            echo "k = $k"
        ;;
    esac
}
```

I put this in a script and source it, so its function is made into an alias for bash (I think). Try running this with various combinations of "-t" and "-f", and you'll see that the variables "$i", "$j", and "$k" all keep their values when running the script again, and that they stay the same in the outer shell, after the script has exited. I am using an Ubuntu 15.04 laptop, and when I type `Ctrl-X` `Ctrl-V` my shell outputs GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).

Everything I have read about bash tells me this should not happen (admittedly, I am somewhat of a beginner in this area). Variables should not stay set after the script (or function) exits, unless you use `export` on them, which I have not. So why is this happening?

Comment: Is this in a script that you're running? Or a file that you're sourcing and then invoking the functions on the command line?

Comment: The 2nd one. I didn't think this mattered for scoping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two different phenomena in play:

1. When variables are **exported**, they are copied into the environments of child processes. Non-exported variables are not passed on. Variables aren't exported unless you explicitly use `export` to mark them for export.

   ```
    export LESS_OPTIONS=-R   # export so `less` sees this variable
    less
   ```

   Don't confuse this with scope, which is different.
2. Inside functions variables have global **scope** by default. You have to use the `local` keyword to declare local variables. Otherwise a loop like `for i in "$@"` will modify the global variable `$i` rather than creating a local variable.

   ```
   svn() {
       local i j k

       case $@ in
           ...
       esac
   }
   ```

Exporting determines what child processes see. Scope determines whether functions modify global variables or not.

Comment: I have not seen this in example bash scripts on the Internet. So I would use something like `local i=$i` in the example above?

Comment: Many scripts out in the wild are poorly written. They leak variables, they don't quote variables properly, they parse the output of `ps` and `ls`... all kinds of nonsense. The [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Functions) has an example that correctly uses `local i` before a `for` loop, along with the note, *"The local variable `i` inside the function is stored differently from the variable `i` in the outer script. This allows the two loops to operate without interfering with each other's counters."*

Comment: It seems that bash's scoping is similar to JavaScript's. Both have 2 types of scoping: global scope (no identifier) and function scope (declared with `var` or `local`). Do I have that about right? I work mainly with JavaScript, so an analogy like this would be helpful to me.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I never made that connection. And I would say JavaScript wins because you can put the `var` declaration right in the `for` loop. In bash it has to be a separate command.

Comment: `declare` can also be used for scoping.  Not using `local` or `declare` is unfortunately a common error.

Comment: Yes, according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419704/differences-between-declare-typeset-and-local-variable-in-bash) declare, local, & typeset are all the same variable in bash.